# Indexer with two keys in python

Tags: python

I'm newbie with python. I want to write a class with two keys as indexer. also need to be able to use them inside of class like this:

```
a = Cartesian(-10,-10,10,10) # Cartesian is the name of my class
a[-5][-1]=10
```

and in the Cartesian class:

```
def fill(self,value):
   self[x][y] = x*y-value
```

I try with

```
def __getitem__(self,x,y):
  return self.data[x-self.dx][y-self.dy]
```

but doesn't work.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you just need a lightweight application, you can have `__getitem__` accept a tuple:

```
def __getitem__(self, c):
  x, y = c
  return self.data[x-self.dx][y-self.dy]

def __setitem__(self, c, v):
  x, y = c
  self.data[x-self.dx][y-self.dy] = v
```

and use like this:

```
a[-5,-1] = 10
```

However, if you are doing a lot of numeric computation or this is integral to your application, consider using Numpy and just represent this coordinate as a vector: [Link](https://numpy.org/)

Comment: Thanks Carl, python is amazing! I don't know what's numpy , i'll try it. (different with python?)

Comment: Numpy is a python library for numeric computing.

Comment: Numpy is a library for Python that makes numeric computation a bit easier (and faster than native Python). It is similar to Matlab, but for Python. You can do matrix and vector operations quite easily.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason you actually need to explicitly define a `Cartesian()` class?  For example, are there calculation methods on it?  If not, then just use a lists within lists to use this type of syntax.

If you *do* need a class, then consider adding a `.coordinate(x, y)` method to it instead and don't bother trying to do the list syntax.

Comment: I'm just trying python, I don't have to accomplish anything! but it sounds like indexers are more beautiful.

Answer (score 1):

Accept a tuple:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def __getitem__(self, key):
...         x, y = key
...         print x, y
... f = Foo()
... f[1,2]
1 2
```

Comment: Thanks, (same answer with below :) ...)